# Creating NSData from NSString in Swift

Tags: xcode, nsstring, nsdata, swift, nsmutableurlrequest

I'm trying to ultimately have an `NSMutableURLRequest` with a valid `HTTPBody`, but I can't seem to get my string data (coming from a `UITextField`) into a usable `NSData` object.

I've seen this method for going the other way:

```
NSString(data data: NSData!, encoding encoding: UInt)
```

But I can't seem to find any documentation for my use case. I'm open to putting the string into some other type if necessary, but none of the initialization options for `NSData` using Swift seem to be what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 371, accepted):

In Swift 3

```
let data = string.data(using: .utf8)
```

---

In Swift 2 (or if you already have a `NSString` instance)

```
let data = string.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```

---

In Swift 1 (or if you have a swift `String`):

```
let data = (string as NSString).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```

---

Also note that  `data` is an `Optional<NSData>` (since the conversion might fail), so you'll need to unwrap it before using it, for instance:

```
if let d = data {
    println(d)
}
```

Comment: Swift can infer NSData type?

Comment: @NicolasManzini sure it can, as with any other type.

Comment: `Value of optional type 'NSData?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?`

Comment: @macdonjo yep, that API changed over time and now it returns an `Optional<NSData>`, which you need to unwrap before using

Comment: @GabrielePetronella In which case its probably cleaner to just use `if let data = (swiftString as NSString).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding){}` to handle the conversation and optional all at once.

Comment: In Swift2, there's no need to use "as" cast since it's automatically bridged

Comment: A conversion to UTF-8 *cannot* fail, therefore an optional binding it not really needed, you can force-unwrap here.

Comment: In Swift 3+ there is a better way: `Data(string.utf8)`. The benefit is that the result is non-optional.

Answer (score 34):

## Swift 4 & 3

Creating `Data` object from `String` object has been changed in Swift 3. Correct version now is:

```
let data = "any string".data(using: .utf8)
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked for me in swift 3 perfectly.  
let input = "test string"
let xdata = input.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

Comment: Any idea why String(data: data!, encoding: .nonLossyASCII) will be nil?

Answer (score 6):

**In swift 5**

```
let data = Data(YourString.utf8)
```

Answer (score 4):

Here very simple method

```
let data = string.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)
```

Answer (score 4):

**Swift 4**

```
let data = myStringVariable.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
```

Comment: Don't use `NSString` in Swift.

Answer (score 4):

**Convert String to Data**

```
extension String {
    func toData() -> Data {
        return Data(self.utf8)
    }
}
```

**Convert Data to String**

```
extension Data {
      func toString() -> String {
          return String(decoding: self, as: UTF8.self)
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
// Checking the format
var urlString: NSString = NSString(data: jsonData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

// Convert your data and set your request's HTTPBody property
var stringData: NSString = NSString(string: "jsonRequest=\(urlString)")

var requestBodyData: NSData = stringData.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
```

Answer (score 3):

To create not optional data I recommend using it:

```
let key = "1234567"
let keyData = Data(key.utf8)
```

Comment: In Swift 3+ this is the most efficient way.

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 4.2**

```
let data = yourString.data(using: .utf8, allowLossyConversion: true)
```