# How to make GET request in swift 3

Tags: swift, api, rest, http, alamofire

I have a project in swift 3 and want to make a GET request. However, Alamofire is not yet updated to swift 3. When will Alamofire support swift 3 and how do you hard code a GET request with parameters in swift 3?

Comment: @EricAya In my case, I don't want use Alamofire with Swift 3, because it's only support iOS 9+.

Comment: Please refer third-party API questions ("When will Alamofire support Swift 3") to their respective GIT pages, not SO.

Answer (score 27):

Swift 3.0

```
    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "http://example.com")!)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    let session = URLSession.shared

    session.dataTask(with: request) {data, response, err in
        print("Entered the completionHandler")
    }.resume()
```

Comment: Thanks! How can I add params?

Comment: same question.. How to add parameters?

Comment: var err: NSError?
        request.HTTPBody = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(params, options: nil, error: &err)
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

Comment: Check this link on how to use param in the request: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27723912/swift-get-request-with-parameters

Answer (score 18):

**Swift 3**

```
let url = URL(string: "http://example.com/get")
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!, completionHandler: {
        (data, response, error) in
        if(error != nil){
            print("error")
        }else{
            do{
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options:.allowFragments) as! [String : AnyObject]


                OperationQueue.main.addOperation({ 
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                })

            }catch let error as NSError{
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }).resume()
```

[REST API In Swift 3 And Xcode 8 Using URLSession And JSONSerialization](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KDgI-sFW7wQ)

Comment: Care to elaborate?

Answer (score 2):

Alamofire will be updated to Swift 3...whenever they get around to it, I guess. GET requests without Alamofire are pretty easy:

```
    let req = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string:"your-endpoint-url?parameter=value")!)
    req.HTTPMethod = "GET"
    req.HTTPBody = "key=\"value\"".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) //This isn't for GET requests, but for POST requests so you would need to change `HTTPMethod` property
    NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(req) { data, response, error in
        if error != nil {
            //Your HTTP request failed.
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        } else {
            //Your HTTP request succeeded
            print(String(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding))
        }
    }.resume()
```

Comment: Do you also know how to add authentication?

Comment: And add parameters?

Comment: @SimonNarang See edit for parameters. For authentication, I assume you mean OAuth? Check out this library: https://github.com/OAuthSwift/OAuthSwift