# How to send parameters with AVPlayer request in iOS swift?

Tags: ios, swift, url, streaming, avplayer

I have a POST request where I have to post parameters (track_id , track_name) to url to get a mp3 file content. Now How can i get this mp3 file streaming in **AVPlayer**?

I know how to stream in AVplayer with an url like :

```
   var player: AVPlayer?
   player = AVPlayer(URL: trackURL)
   player?.play()
```

But here my URL won't have any content unless I provide its required **parameters** (track_id , track_name). How can i set the URL with these 2 parameters?

Comment: I think this link is useful to you  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27723912/swift-get-request-with-parameters

Comment: Yes. But that was for GET request. How can I set URL parameter for POST request?

Comment: you have to try this code?

Comment: Tried. But not working. Guess I have to work on GET instead of POST.

Answer (score -1):

You need to have the url path to the mp3 resource at the time of initialization. Make the POST request first and then initialize the player with the URL that you get in response.