# Web service request in swift corresponding to java code

Tags: java, ios, swift, web-services, nsmutableurlrequest

Given below is my java code which is a part of a sample webservice:

```
@Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext)
    {
        Method method = resourceInfo.getResourceMethod();
        //Access allowed for all
        if( ! method.isAnnotationPresent(PermitAll.class))
        {
            //Access denied for all
            if(method.isAnnotationPresent(DenyAll.class))
            {
                requestContext.abortWith(ACCESS_FORBIDDEN);
                return;
            }

            //Get request headers
            final MultivaluedMap<String, String> headers = requestContext.getHeaders();

            //Fetch authorization header
            final List<String> authorization = headers.get(AUTHORIZATION_PROPERTY);

            //If no authorization information present; block access
            if(authorization == null || authorization.isEmpty())
            {
                requestContext.abortWith(ACCESS_DENIED);
                return;
            }

            //Get encoded username and password
            final String encodedUserPassword = authorization.get(0).replaceFirst(AUTHENTICATION_SCHEME + " ", "");

            //Decode username and password
            String usernameAndPassword = new String(Base64.decode(encodedUserPassword.getBytes()));;

            //Split username and password tokens
            final StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(usernameAndPassword, ":");
            final String username = tokenizer.nextToken();
            final String password = tokenizer.nextToken();

            //Verifying Username and password
            System.out.println(username);
            System.out.println(password);

          //Is user valid?
            if( ! isUserAllowed(username, password))
            {
                requestContext.abortWith(ACCESS_DENIED);
                return;
            }
        }
    }
```

And my swift code to get the response is :

```
let headers = [
        "authorization": "Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=",
        "cache-control": "no-cache"
    ]
    let parameters = ["username" : "admin","password" : "admin"]


    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://192.168.10.229:8080/JerseyDemos/rest/employees")!,
                                      cachePolicy: .UseProtocolCachePolicy,
                                      timeoutInterval: 60.0)
    request.HTTPMethod = "GET"
    //request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers
    do {
        request.HTTPBody = try! NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(parameters, options: [])
    }
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let dataTask = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
        if (error != nil) {
            print(error)
        } else {
            let httpResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse
            print(httpResponse)
        }
    })

    dataTask.resume()
```

But this is not working well. I am getting below error :

> Optional(Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1017 "cannot parse response" UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://192.168.10.229:8080/JerseyDemos/rest/employees, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-1, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://192.168.10.229:8080/JerseyDemos/rest/employees, NSLocalizedDescription=cannot parse response, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4, NSUnderlyingError=0x145319e0 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1017 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-1}}})

How can I make this working? The java service is working fine. I checked it with Postman.

Comment: You might be in that use case: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27724627/2914850.

Comment: @Zico Thanks. That link helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from ios 10 you should use https urls only.

You need to add ssl certificate to your java server.

Comment: we can use http urls in iOS 10 by using <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
 <dict>
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
  <true/>
 </dict> in info.plist

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution from the link Zico has provided. The solution is added below :

```
let parameters = ["username" : "admin","password" : "admin"]
    let parameterString = parameters.stringFromHttpParameters()
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://192.168.10.229:8080/JerseyDemos/rest/employees?\(parameterString)")!,
                                      cachePolicy: .UseProtocolCachePolicy,
                                      timeoutInterval: 60.0)
    request.HTTPMethod = "GET"
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let dataTask = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
        if (error != nil) {
            print(error)
        } else {
            let httpResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse
            print(httpResponse)
        }
    })

    dataTask.resume()
```

I hope this will help other people here.