# URLSession.shared.dataTask correct way to receive data

Tags: ios, swift, api, error-handling, nsurlsessiondatatask

Good day!

I am a little confused in trying to find the correct sequence in checking received (data, response, error) from dataTask and doing some special error handling.

Usually we have URLSession looking like this:

```
class HTTPRequest {
    static func request(urlStr: String, parameters: [String: String], completion: @escaping (_ data: Data?,_ response: URLResponse?, _ error: Error?) -> ()) {
        var url = OpenExchange.base_URL + urlStr
        url += getParameters(param: parameters)
        let request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!)
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print("URLSession Error: \(String(describing: error?.localizedDescription))")
                completion(nil,nil,error)
            } else {
                completion(data,response,nil)
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }

    static func getParameters(param: [String: String]) -> String {
        var data = [String]()
        for (key,value) in param {
            data.append(key + "=\(value)")
        }
        return data.map { String($0) }.joined(separator: "&")
    }

}
```

I have another function that has HTTPRequest inside of it, to wrap everything to and object type I'm working with:

```
 static func networkOperation(urlStr: String, parameters: [String: String], completion: @escaping (ReturnedData) -> () ) {
        var recieved = ReturnedData()
        HTTPRequest.request(urlStr: urlStr, parameters: parameters) { (data, resp, err) in
            if let data = data, let response = resp {

// TODO: try JSONDecoder() if data is API Error Struct; Moderate this section depending on results of decoding;

                recieved.data = data
                recieved.response = response 
                recieved.result = .Success
                completion(recieved)
                return
            } else if err == nil {
                recieved.result = .ErrorUnknown
                completion(recieved)
                return
            }
            recieved.error = err as NSError?
            completion(recieved)
        }
       }

public struct ReturnedData {
    public var data: Data?
    public var response: URLResponse?
    public var error: Error?
    public var result: RequestResult = .ErrorHTTP
}

public enum RequestResult: String {
    case Success
    case ErrorAPI
    case ErrorHTTP
    case ErrorUnknown
}
```

Using the code above I can easily create different networkOperation calls for doing different API methods and handle different Data models that are returned. What I am trying to implement is API Error check. Since my API has some error description for example when you get your APP_ID wrong or current APP_ID has no permission to get information etc.. So if any of these occur the data will look like this:

```
  {
  "error": true,
  "status": 401,
  "message": "invalid_app_id",
  "description": "Invalid App ID provided - please sign up at https://openexchangerates.org/signup, or contact support@openexchangerates.org."
  }
```

I think its not alright trying to decode every received data with Error struct in networkOperations "//TODO" mark, maybe there is some good way to implement this?

Comment: I'd send all server related errors via the `error` parameter of the URL request.

Comment: Unrelated, your `getParameters` is not percent encoding the request. Use `URLComponents` to percent escape it properly. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/27724627/1271826.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should have your API errors return error objects.

E.g. You could do:

```
enum NetworkRequestError: Error {
    case api(_ status: Int, _ code: ApiResultCode, _ description: String)
}
```

Where you code your responses into an `enum` called `ApiResultCode` like so:

```
enum ApiResultCode {
    case invalidAppId
    case recordNotFound   // just an example
    ...
    case unknown(String)
}

extension ApiResultCode {
    static func code(for string: String) -> ApiResultCode {
        switch string {
        case "invalid_app_id":   return .invalidAppId
        case "record_not_found": return .recordNotFound
        ...
        default:                 return .unknown(string)
        }
    }
}
```

This enum lets you check `message` codes without littering your code with string literals.

And if you parse an API error, you could return that. E.g.

```
if responseObject.error {
    let error = NetworkRequestError.api(responseObject.status, ApiResultCode.code(for: responseObject.message), responseObject.description)
    ... now pass this `error`, just like any other `Error` object
}
```

---

If you’re open to a broader redesign, I’d personally suggest

- refactor `RequestResult` to pull out those individual error types (the caller wants to know simply if it succeeded or failed ... if it failed, it should then look at the `Error` object to determine why it failed);
- but have this new `Result` enumeration include associated values, namely the `Data` on success and the `Error` on failure; and
- now that the enumeration includes what we need in its associated values, we can completely eliminate `ReturnedData`.

So, first, let’s expand that `RequestResult` to include the error on failures and the payload on success:

```
public enum Result {
    case success(Data)
    case failure(Error)
}
```

Actually, modern convention is to make this generic, where the above becomes a `Result<Data, Error>` using the following:

```
public enum Result<T, U> {
    case success(T)
    case failure(U)
}
```

(Swift 5 actually includes this generic.)

And I’d then expand `ResultError` to handle both API errors as well as any unknown errors:

```
enum NetworkRequestError: Error {
    case api(_ status: Int, _ code: ApiResultCode, _ description: String)
    case unknown(Data?, URLResponse?)
}
```

So, having done this, you can change `request` to pass back a `Result<Data, Error>`:

```
static func request(urlString: String, parameters: [String: String], completion: @escaping (Result<Data, Error>) -> ()) {
    let request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: urlString)!)
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        guard let responseData = data, error == nil else {
            completion(.failure(error ?? NetworkRequestError.unknown(data, response)))
            return
        }

        completion(.success(responseData))
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

And the caller would then do:

```
request(...) { result in
    switch result {
    case .failure(let error):
        // do something with `error`

    case .success(let data):
        // do something with `data`
    }
}
```

The beauty of this `Result` generic is that it becomes a consistent pattern you can use throughout your code. For example, let’s assume you have some method that is going to parse a `Foo` object out of the `Data` that `request` returned:

```
func retrieveFoo(completion: @escaping (Result<Foo, Error>) -> Void) {
    request(...) { result in
        switch result {
        case .failure(let error):
            completion(.failure(error))

        case .success(let data):
            do {
                let responseObject = try JSONDecoder().decode(ResponseObject.self, from: data)
                if responseObject.error {
                    completion(.failure(NetworkRequestError.api(responseObject.status, ApiResultCode.code(for: responseObject.message), responseObject.description)))
                    return
                }

                let foo = responseObject.foo
                completion(.success(foo))
            } catch {
                completion(.failure(error))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Or, if you wanted to test for a particular API error, e.g. `.recordNotFound`:

```
retrieveFoo { result in
    switch result {
    case .failure(NetworkRequestError.api(_, .recordNotFound, _)):
        // handle specific “record not found” error here

    case .failure(let error):
        // handle all other errors here

    case .success(let foo):
        // do something with `foo`
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for such detailed answer, I am going to try implement this right away. Really made my day, faith in humanity restored.