# How to fix URLQueryItem in swift

Tags: ios, swift, urlcomponents

I need to pass an query param to my `URLComponents`:

```swift
URLQueryItem(name: "scope", value: "channel%3Amanage%3Apolls+channel%3Aread%3Apolls")
```

but when i see the url in debug i see this :

```
scope=channel%253Amanage%253Apolls+channel%253Aread%253Apolls
```

The `%3` transforms in `%253`. Why does this happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don’t percent-encode the value you supply to `URLQueryItem`. `URLQueryItem` does that for you. As it is, you are double percent-encoding it (i.e., it is percent-encoding the `%` of your percent-encoded string).

So, instead, simply supply the simple string, and let `URLComponents` take care of it:

```swift
let queryItem = URLQueryItem(name: "scope", value: "channel:manage:polls+channel:read:polls")
```

---

As an aside, the `:` characters do not need to be percent-encoded when encountered within a query, anyway. E.g.:

```swift
let queryItem = URLQueryItem(name: "scope", value: "channel:manage:polls+channel:read:polls")

var components = URLComponents(string: "https://example.com")
components?.queryItems = [
    queryItem
]

guard let url = components?.url else { return }

print(url) // https://example.com?scope=channel:manage:polls+channel:read:polls
```

See [RFC3986](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986#section-3.4), in which, if you trace `query` back to `pchar`, you will see that `:` does not need to be escaped.

But if there really was anything in that query that needed percent-encoding, `URLQueryItem` and `URLComponents` would take care of it for you. (The one exception is the `+` character as [discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27723912/swift-get-request-with-parameters/27724627#27724627); but I assume from your example that you didn’t want that escaped anyway.)