# Sending data to PHP server

Tags: ios, swift2, xcode7

I'm trying to set up sending data to a PHP server but I'm having no luck at all.

Here is my PHP code.

```
<?php
require_once "../config/config.php";
var_dump($_POST);
var_dump($_REQUEST);
// Read request parameters
if(isset($_REQUEST)){
    $username = $db->escape($_REQUEST["username"]);
    $email = $db->escape($_REQUEST["email"]);
    $password = $db->escape($_REQUEST["password"]);
    $id = MD5($email);
    echo $username;
    //$db->query("INSERT INTO user ('id','username','email','password') VALUES ('$id','$username','$email',PASSWORD('$password'))");
    $returnValue = $id;
}else{
    $returnValue = "No data received";
}
// Send back request in JSON format
echo json_encode($returnValue); 
?>
```

Here is my Swift Code

```
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://***************/register.php")!)

    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

    let data = "username=JoeBloggs&email=joe@bloggs.com&password=12345"

    request.HTTPBody = (data as NSString).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) { (data, response, error) -> Void in
        print(response)
        let strData = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        print(strData)
        print(error)

    }
    task.resume()
```

I'm not concerned about getting a result back yet (I have that working fine). I just can't get any data to the server.

Here is the result from the above script.

```
Optional(<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x7ff9b3d6ea90> { URL: http://iep.almartin.co.uk/register.php } { status code: 200, headers {
"Cache-Control" = "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0";
Connection = close;
"Content-Type" = "text/html; charset=UTF-8";
Date = "Tue, 01 Sep 2015 09:02:46 GMT";
Expires = "Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT";
Pragma = "no-cache";
Server = nginx;
"Set-Cookie" = "PHPSESSID=8j2d7oobg9plvdik1dcbqtoq70; path=/";
"Transfer-Encoding" = Identity;
} })
Optional(array(0) {
 }
 array(0) {
 }
 <br />
 <b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: username in <b>/home/linweb34/i/iep.almartin.co.uk/user/htdocs/register.php</b> on line <b>7</b><br />
 <br />
 <b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: email in <b>/home/linweb34/i/iep.almartin.co.uk/user/htdocs/register.php</b> on line <b>8</b><br />
 <br />
 <b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: password in <b>/home/linweb34/i/iep.almartin.co.uk/user/htdocs/register.php</b> on line <b>9</b><br />
 "d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e")
 nil
```

As you can see both $_REQUEST and $_POST are returning empty arrays.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I followed @vadian answer which didn't work initially. I did some research into why PHP wasn't accepting application/json.

I got it to work by using $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA instead of $_POST or $_REQUEST in the php file.

However! $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA is now depreciated but the following code works

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://input'); 
$obj = json_decode($json);
```

Seems like a PHP hack to me but at least it works.

Answer (score 0):

The error clearly says that there is problem with your MySQL usage. 
Following are the working code template. It uses PDO for DB connection.

```
function __construct() {
    $this->conn = new PDO('mysql:host=<your hostnam>;dbname=<dbname>', '<user>', '<pass>');
    // Generate stack trace on failure.
    $this->conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}

/*
 * Write a function and pass your variables
 */
function get_data_from_db($id,$username,$password,$email) {
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO `user`(`id`,`username`,`email`,`password`) VALUES (:id,:username,:email,PASSWORD(:password))");
    $stmt->execute(array(':id' => $id, ':username' => $username, ':email' => $email, ':password' => $password));
    $data = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $stmt->closeCursor();

    return $data;
}
```

Now in your code, just add a function call and you are done:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST)){
    $username = $db->escape($_REQUEST["username"]);
    $email = $db->escape($_REQUEST["email"]);
    $password = $db->escape($_REQUEST["password"]);
    $id = MD5($email);

    $result = get_result_from_db($id,$username,$password,$email);

    echo json_encode($result);
}
```

Note : Not tested, but it should work.

Comment: You're way off in this. The error in the MySQL isn't the issue. If you look in the response the first error is that $_REQUEST["username"] is an undefined index. In other words it doesn't exist which it should. For some reason the POST from my app isn't reaching the server. That is the issue, not the MySQL.

Comment: Yes, ur right. I thought the problem was with MySQL issue of getting the proper associative index. Also, thought that data is coming to PHP by seeing the var_dump and ISSET conditions.

Comment: Yes, the var_dump is returning empty arrays. I've followed several examples online on how to do this but I can't see why it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Have you checked this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24714566/how-to-send-post-parameters-in-swift

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem.

It seems these lines are the culprit in my app.

```
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
```

It worked fine when I removed them.

Which brings up another question, how do I set up PHP to accept header type "application/json" ?

Comment: the server accepts json, but you're sending html/text. You have to serialize the text with NSJSONSerialization

Answer (score 0):

To send JSON to a server with POST you have to put the data to be sent into a dictionary and serialize the dictionary with `NSJSONSerialization`

```
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://***************/register.php")!)

let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
let postData = ["username" : "JoeBloggs", "email" : "joe@bloggs.com", "password" : "12345"]

do {
  let jsonData = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(postData, options: NSJSONWritingOptions())
  request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
  request.setValue("\(jsonData.length)", forHTTPHeaderField:"Content-Length")
  request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField:"Accept")
  request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField:"Content-Type")
  request.HTTPBody = jsonData

  let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) { (data, response, error) -> Void in
    print(response)
    let strData = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    print(strData)
    print(error)

  }
  task.resume()
} catch let error as NSError {
  print(error)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I had this originally but I was getting the same problem although I didn't have jsonData.length. I'll try this again tonight and see if it works.

Comment: So I tried this and it still doesn't work. Interestingly if I print(jsonData) I get this---- <7b0a2020 22656d61 696c2220 3a20226a 6f654062 6c6f6767 732e636f 6d222c0a 20202270 61737377 6f726422 203a2022 31323334 35222c0a 20202275 7365726e 616d6522 203a2022 4a6f6542 6c6f6767 73220a7d>. I thought Json data was supposed to be readable?

Comment: no, `jsonData` is an `NSData` object like the result of `dataUsingEncoding:`