# Perform POST request in iOS Swift

Tags: ios, post, swift, nsurlconnection

I am trying perform a POST request and the request does not go through. I have looked through [Perform POST request in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24068866/perform-post-request-in-swift) already but it does not contain what I'm looking for.

```
func application(application: UIApplication!, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: NSDictionary!) -> Bool {
    var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "https://us1.lacunaexpanse.com"))
    println("request url https://us1.lacunaexpanse.com")
    var session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

    let apikey = "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
    println("apikey",apikey)

    let username = "username"
    let password = "password"

    var login = Array(["username", "password", "apikey"])

    let jsonDictionary = ["2.0", "jsonrpc", "1", "id", "login", "method", "login", "params"]
    println("jsonDictionary",jsonDictionary)

    var writeError: NSError?

    let jsonData = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(jsonDictionary, options: NSJSONWritingOptions(), error: NSErrorPointer())

    var resultAsString = NSString(data: jsonData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

    resultAsString = resultAsString.stringByAppendingString("empire")

    let url = NSURL.URLWithString("string")
    println("url",url)

    var request2 = NSMutableURLRequest()
    println("Post url =%@",url)

    request2 = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:url)

    request2.HTTPMethod = "POST"

    var connection = NSURLConnection(request: request, delegate: self, startImmediately: false)

    return true
```

Comment: I think you really shouldn't post full URLs and API keys...

Comment: Also, you edited lots of bits before posting, to the point that we don't really know what is actual incorrect code and what is just a bad edit. You use `request2` then `request`, you declare a `login` array but don't use it, you several time use strings instead of the variables you intended to, the append of the "empire" seems more than suspicious... Post actual code with just the API key, username, password and base URL modified, and tell us what the results of your traces are...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are a whole bunch of tactical issues here:

1. You're creating `URLSession`, but then issuing `NSURLConnection` request. Just use `URLSession`.
2. Your “request dictionary” isn't a dictionary, but rather an array. For example, to issue the JSON-RPC request, the proper format of the dictionary is:

   ```swift
   let requestDictionary: [String: Any] = [
       "jsonrpc" : "2.0",
       "id"      : 1,
       "method"  : "login",
       "params"  : ["myuserid", "mypassword", "mykey"]
   ]
   ```
3. Minor issue, but you are using a lot of variables (via `var`) where a constant (via `let`) would be fine. In the spirit of Swift’s safety, use `let` wherever possible.
4. According to the [Lacuna Expanse API](https://us1.lacunaexpanse.com/api/), your URL should be including the module name.

   So, for example if doing `POST` requests in the "Empire" module, the `URL` is:

   ```swift
   let url = URL(string: "https://us1.lacunaexpanse.com/empire")!
   ```
5. You're likely to be doing a lot of requests, so I'd suggest putting the bulk of that in a single function that you can call again and again, without repeating code all over the place. Perhaps a function like the following that takes the following parameters:

   - module (e.g. “empire” vs “alliance”);
   - method (e.g. “login” vs “fetch_captcha”);
   - the parameters appropriate for that request (e.g. for “login”, that would be the “name”, “password”, and the “api_key”); and
   - closure that will be called when the asynchronous request finishes.

   This function then prepares the JSON-RPC request and calls the closure when the request finishes:

   ```
   @discardableResult
   func submitLacunaRequest(module: String, method: String, parameters: Any, completion: @escaping (Result<[String: Any], Error>) -> Void) -> URLSessionTask? {
       let session = URLSession.shared
       let url = URL(string: "https://us1.lacunaexpanse.com")!
           .appendingPathComponent(module)
       var request = URLRequest(url: url)
       request.httpMethod = "POST"
       request.setValue("application/json-rpc", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

       let requestDictionary: [String: Any] = [
           "jsonrpc": "2.0",
           "id"     : 1,
           "method" : method,
           "params" : parameters
       ]

       request.httpBody = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: requestDictionary)

       let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in

           // handle fundamental network errors (e.g. no connectivity)

           guard error == nil, let data = data else {
               completion(.failure(error ?? URLError(.badServerResponse)))
               return
           }

           // check that http status code was 200

           guard
               let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
               200 ..< 300 ~= httpResponse.statusCode
           else {
               completion(.failure(URLError(.badServerResponse)))
               return
           }

           // parse the JSON response

           do {
               guard let responseObject = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? [String: Any] else {
                   throw URLError(.badServerResponse)
               }
               completion(.success(responseObject))
           } catch let parseError {
               completion(.failure(parseError))
           }
       }
       task.resume()

       return task
   }
   ```

   This does all of the necessary wrapping of the method and parameters within a JSON-RPC request. Then, all you need to do to call that method is something like so:

   ```swift
   submitLacunaRequest(module: "empire", method: "login", parameters: ["myuserid", "mypassword", "mykey"]) { result in

       switch result {
       case .failure(let error):
           print("error = \(error)")

       case .success(let value):
           if let errorDictionary = value["error"] as? [String: Any] {
               print("error logging in (bad userid/password?): \(errorDictionary)")
           } else if let resultDictionary = value["result"] as? [String: Any] {
               print("successfully logged in, refer to resultDictionary for details: \(resultDictionary)")
           } else {
               print("we should never get here")
               print("responseObject = \(value)")
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   For a request that requires a dictionary, such as "create", just go ahead and supply the dictionary:

   ```swift
   submitLacunaRequest(module:"empire", method: "create", parameters: [
       "name"      : "user",
       "password"  : "password",
       "password1" : "password",
       "captcha_guid" : "305...dd-....-....-....-e3706...73c0",
       "captcha_solution" : "42",
       "email" : "test@gmail.com"
   ]) { result in
       switch result {
       case .failure(let error):
           print("error = \(error)")

       case .success(let value):
           print("responseObject = \(responseObject)")
       }
   }
   ```

Clearly, in these above, I am just doing minimal error handling, so you could beef this up, but your question was about issuing `POST` request, and hopefully the above illustrates how that is done.

For Swift 2 version, see [previous revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/25376239/4) of this answer.

Comment: Thank you. The entire game is based on JSON RPC requests.

Answer (score 2):

As @jcaron points out, this post is full of bad edits. There's a lot of variables that have different names later in the function and so on. Not to mention you should NEVER post your api key in a SO question or anywhere on the internet for that matter.

To answer your question on to do a post request in Swift, unless you need incredibly granular control over the process, take a look at [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) (same guy that wrote AFNetworking).
A POST request is as simple as `Alamofire.request(.POST, "http://someapiurl.com")` You can also pass in a dictionary of body parameters if you so choose.

Comment: In this case the api key doesn't matter. The api key identifies the client.