# Objective-c Send Post request to json-RPC webservice

Tags: ios, objective-c, post, request, json-rpc

In iOS i want send a POST request to a json-RPC web service. How can i do this?
i read [This Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25341858/perform-post-request-in-ios-swift) before and [this repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25341858/perform-post-request-in-ios-swift) but none of them have helped me.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the popular [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) networking library. This provides full networking functionality and very well documented code. Although you can also use [Apple's networking APIs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/URLLoadingSystem.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000165i) for this.

Simple AFNetworking example:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];

NSDictionary *params = @{@"q":@"Chicago",
                         @"units":@"imperial",
                         @"type":@"like",
                         @"mode":@"json"
                         };

    [manager GET:@"http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather" parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

        //Success

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

        //Failure

    }];
```

Answer (score 0):

There is this [AFJSONRPCClient](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFJSONRPCClient), which is a JSON-RPC Client built on AFNetworking.

Hope it helps.