# Character Pointer in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, ios8, character

I am converting by Obj-C code to Swift, but from last 2 days I am stuck on third line in below Obj-C code.

```
char encodedChar = (int)c + (int)kc;

NSLog(@"Encoded Char : %c", encodedChar);     //prints like, Î, ¾, Ü etc.

const void *pt = &encodedChar;

[encodedData appendData:[NSData dataWithBytes:pt length:1]];
```

And this is my Swift Code,

```
let encodedChar = "\(character)".toInt()! + numbers[index]

let characterString = String(stringInterpolationSegment: UnicodeScalar(encodedChar))

println("Encoded Char String : \(characterString)")    //prints same, Î, ¾, Ü etc.
```

But what next, what would be swift equivalent of : `const void *pt = &encodedChar;`

I do not want to convert my string to NSData. Because it behaves differently.

Any suggestion will be helpful, Thanks :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating NSData from NSString in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24039868/creating-nsdata-from-nsstring-in-swift). Swift won't let you access character pointers "just like that" from a `String`.

Comment: I think you don't need to do that you can also use this objective-c class in swift by  Bridging look at this link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002369/how-to-call-objective-c-code-from-swift

Comment: @harish Thnxx for suggesstion, but i need to use pure swifty code.

Comment: @zneak Accessing pointers and converting into Data are two different things, how can it be duplicate.

Comment: @RoNiT, I thought you wanted to append it as data. That's what your Objective-C code does.

Comment: @Zneak Thnxx your suggestion worked, i got my answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got answer,

```
var encodedChar = "\(character)".toInt()! + keyNumbers[index]

let data = NSData(bytes: &encodedChar, length: 1)
encodedData.appendData(data)
```