# Create an NSData object from a String

Tags: string, swift, nsstring, plist, nsdata

My app requires the ability to take a `String` and save it to an `NSDictionary` as an `NSData` object, such that when the `NSDictionary` is written to a `.plist` file the resulting file contains the data as `<data>The String as the user typed it (no encoding)</data>`. Is there anyway to do that without manually writing the XML for the `.plist` file?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24039868/creating-nsdata-from-nsstring-in-swift

Comment: As I said in my question, I don't want to encode the String.

Comment: @thefredelement What I would like is the equivalent of `"<data>\(myTextView.text)</data>`, but without manually writing the XML.

Answer (score 3):

There's no way to do what you want.

First, it makes no sense to claim that you don't want the string encoded. Encoding is the process of producing a byte stream from a string. Without encoding, there's no representation of the string. Strings are abstract. They have no concrete representation in and of themselves. Only encoding produces that.

Anyway, that's just not how `NSData` objects are serialized to property list files. Even if you manually wrote the file, it wouldn't really be a correct property list file and no other property-list-reading program would be able to parse it. How did you come to conclude that your app requires this ability?

Comment: To answer your question of how I came to conclude that my app requires this ability, my app is a property list editor. What I would like is the equivalent of `"<data>\(myTextView.text)</data>`, but without manually writing the XML. Just to be sure, are you saying that this is impossible? (I'm not sure if my original question was completely clear.)

Comment: It's possible to write any file contents you like, but what you describe would not be a plist file that any other app would be able to parse. The `data` element of the property list XML schema is a Base64-encoded byte stream. If some other plist-reading app tries to read your format, it will attempt to Base64-decode plain text and get an error at best or garbled data at worst. Beyond that, `myTextView.text` may not be valid to just insert into XML, anyway. If you're writing a property list editor, you should use `NSPropertyListSerialization` to serialize the objects.

Comment: My intention was to have a `UITextView` where the user could enter pre-Base64-encoded text. It seems it would make more sense to just leave data objects out, as they are probably (almost) never written manually.

Comment: If your users are actually interested in entering data objects, you could build various interface mechanisms. Let them pick a file. Let them enter data in other forms (plain text, images, color picker, etc.) and specify an appropriate conversion. Add a hex editor interface or something. If you're going to let them enter Base64-encoded data as text, then your program should decode it, store the resulting byte stream in an `NSData`, put that in the object hierarchy, and serialize it in the plist like normal.