# my json start with XML <string> [{.....}] </string> how can I parse it?

Tags: ios, swift

The result come like this start with XML, Can I remove the XML part using code, thanks for helping it is been 4 weeks now I couldn't find a similar case online

[image]

Comment: remove the first x charachters, where is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this XML/HTML parser: [Fuzi](https://github.com/cezheng/Fuzi)

```
import Fuzi

Alamofire.request(.GET, url)
    .responseString { response in
        do {
            let doc = try XMLDocument(string: response.result.value)
            if let root = doc.root {
                 // this should be the content within the <string></string> element
                print(root.stringValue)
            }
        } catch let error {
            print(error)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thx alot it did work and now i have the  JSON with out the XML but how cab i display it i tried: 
                      let jsson = root.stringValue
                        print(jsson) 
                       let json = JSON(jsson)
                        let name = json[0]["FromEmirateNameAr"].stringValue
                        print(name)  :

Comment: what json library are you using though? I recommend you take a look at this one: https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON

Comment: and tried .string instead of .stringValue it gived null  ,  also i tried                    let json =JSON(root.stringValue)                                           if let jsonArray = json.array{  for item in jsonArray
  {
 if let jsonDict = item.dictionary //jsonDict : [String : JSON]?
 {
  let postId = jsonDict["FromEmirateNameAr"]!.intValue
 let text = jsonDict["FromRegionNameAr"]!.stringValue
   print(postId)
print(text)
}
 }
} // and i can't access to the data inside of for  sorry for asking again thanks for your help ^^

Comment: i'm using SwiftyJson   when i tried : let jsson = root.stringValue
                        print(jsson)
                      json = JSON(data: jsson)  // it made an error ((data: String)' is not convertible to '(data: NSData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions, error: NSErrorPointer)) ( Cannot assign a value of type 'String' to a value of type 'NSData')

Comment: Json(data:) takes an NSData param I guess. Convert the string into NSData then do it again

Comment: still can't  get  it i will keep trying tho do u know anyway to do so ? sorry i keep asking u :P

Comment: make use of google, you can find out many of these answers yourself http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24039868/creating-nsdata-from-nsstring-in-swift

Comment: sorry for bothering you but i did search but i'm still new at this sorry again for bothering u ^^

Answer (score 0):

This is not json response. It xml reponse. You can't parse this by json serialization.

You need a **XML parser** to **parse** this response. For more [see](http://www.appcoda.com/parse-xml-and-json-web-service/) this tutorial.

Comment: ya but this tutorial is for object C not swift and i'm still a beginner  , but  i appreciate your help thx ^^

Answer (score 0):

Actually XML format in the response supersedes JSON, so you will need to parse first XML (NSXMLParser, [RaptureXML](https://github.com/siuying/RaptureXML), AFXMLParserResponseSerializer) and then the object you obtain will be JSON string which you need.